# CentOS 6.5 network disconnected

Tags: wired-networking

My English is not good, so I would appreciate if you give simple solutions.

Centos operating in VMware is using a bridge-connection.

I created a 'network':

[image]

Configuration 2:

[image: Image2]

Comment: What does `ifconfig -a` show? Is the NIC connected in VMware?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Edit WMware virtual network.

[image]

Comment: This would be a *far* more useful answer to many visitors if you can provide at least some translation of the UI element texts involved.